# Google map api3, downloadxml.js, Syntax to include image in info window

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I try to adapt my xml files to work with google's api3 based on geocodezip's tutorial using downloadxml.js:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html

It works only partially: Text shows in the info window, however images are not displayed anymore.
Here an example of my xml line (worked in api2, but shows only text in api3):

`<marker lat="-27.471000" lng="153.023400" html='Brisbane&lt;br&gt;&lt;img src="DarkSide.jpg" width=100&gt;' label="21 Pics" />`

Has the syntax for images changed in api3?
Thanks for help

Comment: Please post your code that displays the map and exhibits the problem.  [images in infowindows work for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=example3.xml)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The problem was resolved after I cleared the cache in my browser. Now it works perfectly!

Comment: @geocodezip Btw: Thanks for your tutorials. One more question: Would it be possible to include a button in the infowindow like this [Picasa](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18809878/Picasa.jpg) My code is here: [Map](http://schafkopf88.funpic.de/) I have no knowledge on java and I am looking for something like this for a long time